# How do I fill javascript array with HTML attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checkboxes in my table rows with an attribute 'result-id'.
How do I fill a javascript array with the values stored in 'result-id' checkbox, inside the table row.

I already figured out how to acces the data in jquery, now I just want to store that data inside of an array.

It looks a little something like this :

```
   <td>
      <input result-id="@item.Id" type="checkbox" />
   </td>
```

This is the jquery I have now, it only adds one item (last clicked checkbox id)

```
        $(tableBody).find('tr').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('input:checkbox').prop("checked") == true) {
                resultList.fill(parseInt($(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('result-id')));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to:

- Filter out the unchecked checkboxes (`:not(:checked)`, or `.filter`, ...)
- Use `map` on the result to get a jQuery set containing the `result-id` values (by returning `this.getAttribute("result-id")` or `$(this).attr("result-id")`)
- Use `get` on it to get the actual array

For instance:

```
var array = $(tableBody).find("tr input:checkbox:not(:checked)")
    .map(function() {
        return this.getAttribute("result-id");
    })
    .get();
```

That uses the jQuery-specific `:checked` pseudo-class to only look at checked checkboxes, and uses the DOM directly to get the attribute value.

You could also do it without using a jQuery-specific selector:

```
var array = $(tableBody).find("tr input[type=checkbox")
    .filter(function() { return this.checked; })
    .map(function() {
        return this.getAttribute("result-id");
    })
    .get();
```

Or without using jQuery at all (here I'm assuming `tableBody` is a DOM element, not a jQuery set, and a modern browser):

```
const array = Array.from(tableBody.querySelectorAll("tr input[type=checkbox"))
    .filter(({checked}) => checked)
    .map(cb => cb.getAttribute("result-id"));
```